# Memcached: providing TTL setting while connection creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I want to set the TTL for the keys while creating the connection. Right now I am setting it while writing to the cache. Is there a configuration parameter for this?

Answer (score 1):

on your application.rb or some environment file:

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store,{:default_ttl=>1.days.to_i}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-rails1/), the options to `MemCache.new` will accept a `:ttl` entry.